# Group Policy Mapping Printer

Tags: active-directory, group-policy

There seems to be lots of different ways to map printers, all appear not to work (for me).
Im running a Windows 2008 Environment with windows 7 clients, simple, hey?

No..

1. I have a printer connected to my windows 2008r2 printer server that is shared.
2. I have a GP with the following setting:

   - Computer Configuration >> Policies >> Administrative Templates >>Only use Package Point and print  (set to disabled)
   - User Configuration >> Preferences >>Windows Settings>> Printer Connections> Added Printer
     [image]
     [image]

Then when I then log in and check event viewer I see the following error
[image]

Double checking the printer additional driver options shows as follows:

[image]

Ive spent 2 hours trying to solve this, should be simple right? any ideas?

Comment: You say both settings are in one GPO. Are there users *and their computers* in the OU or sub-OUs that this is applying to?

Comment: its applying to a sub-OU with users in it

Comment: How are your [Point and Print Restrictions](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc725938.aspx) configured?

Comment: You've configured point and print restrictions as a computer policy but you're not applying to to any computers. Do you see the issue there?

Comment: I've actaully set it to both user config and computer, however, your right that only the user is in the sub-ou and not the machine, i applied the computer config point and print restriction at the root of my GP and it worked, ty